# XPath - Find parent when no children with attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to find every reference to a node (report) that does not have a child node (property) with a specific attributes values.

My xml is:

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design">
<property name="comments">comment</property>
<property name="test">sdcs</property>
<property name="eventHandlerClass">sdcs</property>
</report>
```

and my XPath is:

```
/*[local-name()='report'][not(/*[local-name()='property'][@name='eventHandlerClass'])]
```

Problem is, it is returning the report when I'm looking for it to not return anything.

Any idea's on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your report contains a property that is not an evenHandlerClass. You want to say there is no such child, which could be done by counting such children and getting zero:

```
/*[local-name()='report'][count(*[(local-name()='property' and @name="eventHandlerClass")])=0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please register a namespace before you execute your XPath.

Using `local-name()` works but it produces very inelegant (and inefficient) XPath.

Supposing you have registered `"http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design"` as `birt`:

```
//birt:report[not(birt:property[@name='eventHandlerClass'])]
```

If for some reason you cannot register a namespace, use (wrapped for legibility)

```
//*[
  local-name() = 'report' 
  and not(
    *[@local-name() = 'property' and @name='eventHandlerClass']
  )
]
```